# drop down select list in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to generate a drop down select list with the form helper of CakePHP,

I'am trying to pass an array in the `$this->Form->input()` method which is obtained in the folowing
way `$colors = $this->Color->find('all',...);$this->set('colors', $colors);`.

thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

What I'm trying to do in CakePHP is this (in SQL code):

```
SELECT id, color 
FROM colors Color WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT color_id FROM product_size_colors psc WHERE psc.product_id=16);
```

How can I replicate the above query in cakephp?

Answer (score 0):

find('list') is what you need to look into...

by default thats going to get the id,name fields..

$colors = $this->Color->find('list');
$this->set('colors', $colors);